# Scope of variable defined in included file in Julia

Tags: scope, julia

I have an input file where some variables are defined.  For each iteration in a loop, I would like to read the file, update the values of some of the variables, then run calculations.

I have an input file called input.jl with

```
myval=1
```

Then I have a file myscript.jl with the following commands

```
for i=1:2
    include("input.jl")
    println(myval)
    myval=2
end
```

If I run the file (julia myscript.jl), I get an error that `myval` is not defined.  If I comment out the third or fourth lines, then it runs with no problem.  If I remove the for loop, the three lines run with no problem.  How can I read `myval` from input.jl, use it, then update its value during each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the `include` function executes things at global scope, and then continues from where it left off. So if you're trying to dynamically `include` new variables into local scope, this is not the way to do it.

You can either introduce the variable at global scope *first* so that the function has access to it, and therefore the assignment will work (but, be aware that the variable will be updated at the *global* scope).

*or*

you can cheat by wrapping your input file into a module first. You still need to call the variable by its name, and you will get warnings about updating the module, but this way you can update your *local* variable dynamically at least, without needing that variable at global scope:

```
# in input.jl
module Input
  myval  = 1;
end
```

```
# in your main file
for i=1:2
  include("input.jl")
  myval = Input.myval;
  println(myval)
  myval=2
end
```

*or*

you could add a separate process and offload the calculation to *its* global scope, and retrieve it to your current process locally, e.g.

```
# in file input.jl
myval = 1

# in main file
addprocs(1);

for i=1:2
    myval = remotecall_fetch(() -> (global myval; include("input.jl"); myval), 2);
    println(myval)
    myval=2
end
```

Comment: (obviously, reimporting a module is *technically* the same as "defining something at global scope and then using it", but, you know, potayto potahto)

Comment: Module scope is still considered "global scope" for the purposes of const'ness, type-inference, etc. The same warnings about performance implications apply.

Comment: @Isaiah yes, I know, though it's good to point this out explicitly, thanks. I do feel that the julia developers have taken some draconian measures to prevent inefficiencies in a lot of cases, where they completely failed to take into account the "human factor". (i.e. if the easiest way to work around it is 10 times less efficient, this is what's going to happen anyway, so they may as well have provided a slightly less efficient 'local' option anyway and just follow it up with appropriate warnings). Maybe it was a decision based on limitations of the language instead though, I don't know.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are getting at, but a major reason Julia can be competitively fast without a Google-level VM engineering budget is precisely because this sort of local dynamism is not allowed, so types can be accurately inferred and loops compiled to run efficiently. Dynamism is instead provided through multiple dispatch, metaprogramming, etc. You are free to run code through eval, but you'll quickly discover the penalty for interpretation is often much more than 10x.

Comment: @Isaiah yes exactly. The developers have made the decision to disallow "local eval" because it's innefficient, hoping that its absence will encourage "good practices" that ensure efficiency, and have left "global eval" in as a last resort for edge cases. The flaw with this plan is that "humans" are more likely to rely on a "workaround" which is 10 times slower than even what a "local eval" woud be, rather than "good practices" which might require putting in 10 times the effort. It's the kind of "behavioural economics" that might lead to julia being branded as "slow in practice" in the long run

Comment: To be clear, I am not *recommending* the techniques in my answer in favour of a more "good practices" approach. or implying this is an appropriate / efficient way of doing it. I'm just saying, this is in fact the answer to the user's question, i.e. the "workaround" to "make `include` work in this scenario". It's implicit that this is a very innefficient "workaround", but in practice the user probably doesn't care at this "proof-of-concept" stage and the provision of a "local eval" by the language itself (provided with appropriate disclaimers) would have made this nasty workaround unnecessary.